# Django REST Framework ModelSerializer - Object not saved

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've a model, and one of it's field refers to an overrided User instance (changed in Django settings).

When I'm performing a POST from my client, the route ends up here at the `create` method:

```
class CatView(ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = CatListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Cat.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).order_by('id')

    '''
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = CatGetSerializer(Cat.objects.filter(owner=request.user), context={'request': request}, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    '''

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = CatPutSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.create(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When using a PUT to do a partial update on my model, it works fine. But creating one just doesn't work. I manually inject the `user` instance into the serializer and asks it to create the object. Then... nothing. No exception raises, it returns the proper data, but the object is not in my database, not being saved.

What's the issue here?

**EDIT**:

When I'm adding the `owner` field to the CatPutSerializer, it opens security issues since I don't know how to prevent this to be changed as I don't want the client to send me which user to assign. And when I'm duplicating the serializer to be used on POST only requests, it says it misses the `owner` field...

Here's the `CatPutSerializer`:

```
class CatPutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cat
        fields = ('name', 'weight', 'sterilized', 'image', 'tag', 'dob', 'race', 'gender')
```

**UPDATE**:

As suggested, I'm now doing as follows :

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pdb.set_trace()
    serializer = CatPutSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Though removed the `perform_create` overriding.

**SOLUTION**:

After further investigation, it doesn't seem related to `drf` but to Django / PostgreSQL itself, so I checked to Django model `save` method, and it seems that my custom image processing prevented from new objects to be created... Changed it and now works.

Comment: Are you trying to create using PUT?

Comment: No, actually the serializer is the same for PUT and POST with partial and non partial arguments, tough I should change its name.

Comment: Well, it looks ok to me, haha. Can you please post a sample request and the response you get back even when the data is not saved?

Comment: Here it is :

Sending as multipart/form-data: 
`dob: "1997-01-07"
gender: "M"
image: null
name: "aze"
race: "Devon Rex"
sterilized: false
tag: "null"
weight: 23`

Receiving : 201 Created / application/json
`{"name":"aze","weight":23,"sterilized":false,"image":null,"tag":"null","dob":"1997-01-07","race":"Devon Rex","gender":"M"}`

Comment: As you go through the debugger, you should see if the execution ever reaches the `serializer.save()` step (put a breakpoint there), because that is where the db save happens. If it does not, you'd know where the problem is and you can work on that so that it hits `serializer.save`. If it hits `serializer.save()` then the question is did you override your serializer's `save` method?

Comment: Weirdest stuff ever,it goes through `save`, didn't overwrite serializer's `save` method. It even returns the instance, and seems to be saved. But it's not. Even checked manually trough `psql`, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be overriding both `create` and `perform_create`. If you look at the code for [CreateModelMixin](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py) which the `ModelViewSet` inherits from you will notice that `create` calls `perform_create`, which calls `serializer.save()`. You don't call `perform_create` in your `create` method; you seem to be calling `serializer.create(...)`. If you are overriding `create`, simply do this:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = CatPutSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's the way I tried to do it in the first place, and wasn't working aswell. I removed the `perform_create` overriding. Did I miss something? I'll add my serializer as an edit.